# Intel IPP or OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, intel-ipp

I would like to specialize in image and video processing. Which library is better for signal processing, Intel IPP or OpenCV? What are the differences between them?

Comment: In my working place,my colleges use Intel IPP and they said that IPP was good.i will use the library for my works and graduate thesis.

Comment: If you wish to specialise in image and video processing, use both and learn their relative strengths and weaknesses.  Teach yourself to answer this sort of question.

Comment: Hi Mark,Why do i learn both of them??? Dont they do the same job?One of them is free and the other one is commercial.but in web, opencv is more known than ipp but as i saw ipp is more convenient for commercial big projects.for now the most obvious difference is to display image or video,in ipp you can not display but in opencv you can.but i am a newbie so i miss differences and i asked you

Comment: Doesn't OpenCV use IPP itself for appropriate functions if it detects its presence? Why reinvent the processing routines yourself on top of IPP if you can just use OpenCV?

Comment: Does Intel IPP has a built in function to display images?

Comment: I expect it does and it does more than that, if you don't get it for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it does not seem like an either-or situation.

[You can check the differences and how they work together right from the Intel guys.](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-open-source-computer-vision-library-opencv-faq#1)

For some of us it might matter that while **OpenCV is free, IPP is not**. (When I checked a license was ~$200.) However it covers areas other than image/video processing (it also covers sound processing and cryptography for example).

Answer (score 4):

You might not need to pick one or the other. If you have IPP installed, then you can compile OpenCV to call IPP internally. I think the OpenCV compiler flag for this is `USE_IPP`.

You can investigate whether the OpenCV functionality that you'd like to use can take advantage of the IPP back end.

If you tell us more about what you're building, I can give more detailed advice on the trade-offs with IPP, OpenCV, or some blend of the two.

Comment: WITH_IPP is the name of the flag